# Manage CSS Assets By Page (Odoo)

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10

What is the best way to incorporate css / js assets into Odoo's website where the assets are only loaded for a particular page?

In the examples and documentation they speak of dumping your assets into Odoo's `website.assets_frontend` and I do this however there are circumstances where I would like to use website templates found online and I really do not want to take the time to look through the css classes and identify conflicts.

If the page itself were to fail that is one thing but if it breaks all the css on my existing pages that is another.

I was thinking of using a technique like this.

`t-if="request.httprequest.path.startswith('/page/path/')"`

Using an if statement to determine whether or not to incorporate the css in the website assets or not.

```
<odoo>
    <data>
        <template id="page_style" name="Page Style" inherit_id="website.assets_frontend">
            <xpath expr="link[last()]" position="after">
                <t t-if="request.httprequest.path.startswith('/page/path/')">
                    <link href="/addon_name/path/to/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
                </t>
            </xpath>
        </template>
    </data> 
</odoo>
```

Anyways, if anyone would like to make a suggestion on how they incorporate css into Odoo's frontend assets in a contained way I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is actually insert a:

```
<head>
      <link href="/addon_name/path/to/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
```

to your template that you want the specific css/js to be applied to. For a specific example see `addons/website_google_map/views/google_map_templates.xml`

Your the contents of your head tag will be inserted inside the head tag of the final HTML that will be rendered for that template.

Since it seems to be straighforward and used by the framework itself I have resorted on using it on my own with no problems so far. As I can understand you can also create a javascript Widget that will operate on your template only that will apply a specific css. But the above solution seems cleaner to me.

Comment: can you do the same with js assets? So you are saying that all the `<head/>` assets will be combined and served in one head tag to the client?

Comment: George, I did this on a frontend template. Added the `<head><xml></head>` to my template. Oddly enough the `<head/>` tag was removed and the css link was placed at the top of my `<main/>` element. Now this technically does what I need because my page does have the appropriate css however this does not add the css to the `<head/>` element and does not add the css to the frontend assets. The fact that it is not in the `<head/>` element is not a big deal however the assets package does improve speed by minimising requests.

Comment: Could you check your css to see if it is being placed in the `<head/>` tag and if so provide a working example. My template is enclosed in a `<t t-call="website.layout"/>` if it is not found in the head just modify your answer and I will mark it as correct. By the lack of other comments I will assume what I am doing or what you are suggesting are the only sensible approaches or nobody cares.